# Acccept insure cert in seleniumwebdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use accept insecure cert in selenium web driver but it is not working. Please check for any possible error in below code. I noticed the tutorial uses `WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();` in line 1, instead of   `ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();`

```
    ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
    DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
    dc.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
    ChromeOptions coptions = new ChromeOptions();
    coptions.merge(dc);
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(coptions);
    driver.get("https://expired.badssl.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issues in code you provided - it should work and it works for me.

You can try to set this property to `ChromeOptions` directly.

For example, this code also works for me in your case:

```js
WebDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get("https://expired.badssl.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```